# mpv volume controls via keyboard or mouse under macos?

Tags: macos, video, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, mpv

I'm using `mpv` version 0.33.1 under `macos Big Sur` (version 11.6.1).

It works pretty well, except I cannot figure out how to use the keyboard or the mouse to change the volume while a video is playing. There is a small volume icon at the right side of the `osc` area, but it can only be used for muting or unmuting the volume.

The keyboard arrow keys all step through the video, either forwards or backwards.

The scroll wheel on the mouse also steps through the video.

I have tried all the possible combinations of Shift, Ctrl, Option, and Command with all possible mouse buttons, but none of these affect the video volume.

I can change the volume by sliding left or right on the touch pad, but I am wanting a mouse-based or keyboard-based method for changing the volume.

Ideally, I'd like to remap the arrow keys so that they alter the volume instead of stepping through the video.

Is this or some other mouse-or-keyboard volume control method possible?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control)?

You can decrease/increase the volume in several ways:

```
9    decrease
0    increase

/    decrease
*    increase
```

If your mouse supports it, you can use the mouse wheel…

```
Wheel left/right
    Decrease/increase volume
```

Within the OSC, you can use the mouse wheel to increase or decrease volume while hovering over the volume indicator.

```
mouse wheel     volume up/down
```

Finally, you can create an `input.conf` file and add commands to it. The documentation explains how. I have the following in my own file to change the volume by 10% with each button press.

```
- add volume -10
= add volume 10
```

Comment: I missed that part of the manual when reading it before. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: It's a big manual, that's for sure. Glad it helped.